# Using generics in function typing

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create an interface for a function using generics, such that the function takes in two arguments, and returns either the type of the first argument, or a union of the two. I had thought it was possible to do something like this:

```
declare interface CustomMerge {
  (x: Partial<T1>, y: Partial<T1 | T2>): T1 | T1 & T2;
}
```

But I get all sorts of errors about unexpected symbols here, so I suspect I'm quite a way off the mark with what I've done so far. Is this possible with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare [type variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables) before using them anywhere including function signatures. To do that, you have two options:

**Declare on method level**

```
declare interface CustomMerge {
   <T1, T2>(x: Partial<T1>, y: Partial<T1 | T2>): T1 | T1 & T2;
// ^^^^^^^^
}
```

**Declare on interface level**

```
declare interface CustomMerge<T1, T2> {
//                           ^^^^^^^^
  (x: Partial<T1>, y: Partial<T1 | T2>): T1 | T1 & T2;
}
```

Comment: This is great, and has solved my problem, thanks. This is all working, I'll accept the answer once I'm able to.